# Java RMI, cant find stub class , java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;

Tags: java, client-server, rmi, stub

I am trying to run my rmi program. However it cant seem to find my stub class. I do the command 'start rmiregistry' which starts successfully. 
then after doing :

```
java -classpath . -Djava.security.policy=AllSecurity.policy RMIAuctionManagerImpl
```

I get the following error :

```
Failed to register object java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in
server thread; nested exception is:
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested excep
tion is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIAuctionManagerImpl_Stub
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exce
ption is:
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested excep
tion is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIAuctionManagerImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:419
)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:5
53)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTranspor
t.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport
.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Stream
 RemoteCall.java:273)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:
 251)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:377)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Naming.java:177)
    at RMIAuctionManagerImpl.main(RMIAuctionManagerImpl.java:133)
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested ex
ception is:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIAuctionManagerImpl_Stub
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:409
)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:267)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:174)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:5
53)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTranspor
t.java:808)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport
.java:667)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIAuctionManagerImpl_Stub
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:453)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:184)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:264)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.jav
a:216)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:159
3)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1514)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1
750)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    ... 13 more
```

I have tired this on different computers and i don't get this problem, it just seems to happen on my laptop, is there a problem with my environmental variables ? I checked and my environmental variables where the same as the other PC i tired running this on.

Here is the code  for my class :

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class RMIAuctionManagerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements          RMIAuctionManager, Serializable {

protected ArrayList<RMIAuctionItem> itemList ;
protected ArrayList<RMIBidder> bidderList;

public RMIAuctionManagerImpl() throws RemoteException
{
    itemList= new ArrayList<RMIAuctionItem>();
    bidderList=new ArrayList<RMIBidder>();
}

public ArrayList<RMIBidder> getBidders() throws RemoteException
{
    return bidderList;
}

public ArrayList<RMIAuctionItem> getItems() throws RemoteException
{
    return itemList;
}

public RMIAuctionItem findItem(String itemName) throws RemoteException
{
    for(int i =0; i<itemList.size();i++)
    {
        if(itemList.get(i).getName()==itemName)
        {
            return itemList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;    
}
public void add(RMIBidder aBidder) throws RemoteException
{
    bidderList.add(aBidder);
}
public void sendMessageToServer(RMIAuctionItem aItem, RMIBidder aBidder, double theMessage) throws RemoteException
{
    Connection conn =null;
    PreparedStatement prestmt = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Driver Not Found");
            e.printStackTrace();
    }



     try {

         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:RMIAuctionHouseDB");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Not Found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     try {
            String insertSQL = "Insert into RMIAuctionHouse (ItemName, ClientName, BidAmount) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            prestmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
            prestmt.setString(1, aItem.getName());
            prestmt.setString(2, aBidder.getName());
            prestmt.setDouble(3, theMessage);

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            System.out.println("Statement Not Found");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


         try {
             prestmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Sql Query Not Found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            prestmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        aItem.makeBid(aBidder, theMessage);
}

public void joinBidding(RMIBidder aBidder,RMIAuctionItem aItem) throws RemoteException
{
    System.out.println("Bound Client: "+ aBidder.getName()+ " to "+ aItem.getName());
    aItem.joinBidding(aBidder);
}

public void setItems() throws RemoteException
{
    RMIAuctionItem aItem=new RMIAuctionItemImpl();
    aItem.setName("Ps3");
    aItem.setPrice(200);
    RMIAuctionItem aItem2= new RMIAuctionItemImpl();
    aItem2.setName("Macbook");
    aItem2.setPrice(500);
    RMIAuctionItem aItem3=new RMIAuctionItemImpl();
    aItem3.setName("HTC Desire HD");
    aItem3.setPrice(100);
    itemList.add(aItem);
    itemList.add(aItem2);
    itemList.add(aItem3);
}

public void deleteItems() throws RemoteException
{
    for(int i=0; i<itemList.size();i++)
    {
        itemList.remove(itemList.get(i));
    }
}


public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try{
        RMIAuctionManager myRMIAuctionManager=new RMIAuctionManagerImpl();

        Naming.rebind("RMIAuctionServer", myRMIAuctionManager);

        //myRMIAuctionManager.deleteItems();
        //myRMIAuctionManager.setItems();

        System.out.println("Remote object bound to registry");
    }
    catch( Exception e){

        System.out.println("Failed to register object " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);

 }
}
   }
```

Thanks for any Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *RMI Registry* can't find that class. So there is some difference in your laptop's setup concerning the Registry.

Comment: Track down the difference I specified and rectify it. Clearly it involves the effective CLASSPATH when the Registry is started.

Comment: I solved the problem. my .classpth and .project files where outside the source folder. I was using eclipse. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Be sure you start `rmiregistry` from a directory that has access to your classes (bin/ root folder, not in package folder)

Comment: Thanks, spent 2 days figuring out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a classpath issue. What I would do is print out the java classpath in your code when it starts. Then compare the classpath used on the different machines. The other computers may have a classpath that include the missing class or jar file your program is looking for on your pc.

[Java Tips - How to print classpath](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-print-classpath.html)

Comment: thanks for your reply. So ive ran the that program on the 2 different machines and it just prints out where my .class files are